# Why is my iPhone using buit-in mic instead of my Bluetooth headset?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, headphones, microphone

Why does my iPhone's built-in microphone remain active when I connect it to my bluetooth headset? It should use the headset's mic. Can anybody tell me what’s wrong?

Device: iPhone 7 Plus

Headset: JBL T500BT